# Unit test an external facing function

Tags: django, api, unit-testing, nose

I am trying to write unit test case for an external facing api of my Django application. I have a model called `Dummy` with two fields `temp` and `content`. The following function is called by third party to fetch the `content` field. `temp` is an indexed unique key.

```
@csrf_exempt
def fetch_dummy_content(request):
    try:
        temp = request.GET.get("temp")
        dummy_obj = Dummy.objects.get(temp=temp)
    except Dummy.DoesNotExist:
        content = 'Object not found.'
    else:
        content = dummy_obj.content

    return HttpResponse(content, content_type='text/plain')
```

I have the following unit test case.

```
def test_dummy_content(self):
    params = {
        'temp': 'abc'
    }
    dummy_obj = mommy.make(
        'Dummy',
        temp='abc',
        content='Hello World'
    )
    response = self.client.get(
        '/fetch_dummy_content/',
        params=params
    )
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
    self.assertEqual(response.content, 'Hello World')
```

Every time I run the test case, it goes into `exception` and returns `Object not found.` instead of `Hello World`. Uponn further debugging I found that `temp` from request object inside view function is always `None`, even though I am passing it in `params`.

I might be missing something and not able to figure out. What's the proper way to test these kind of functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[There's no `params` parameter for the `get`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.Client.get) or any of the other functions on the client, you're probably thinking of `data`.

```
response = self.client.get(
    '/fetch_dummy_content/',
    data=params
)
```

It's the second argument anyway, so you can just do `self.client.get('/fetch_dummy_content/', params)` too.

Any unknown parameters get included in the environment which explains why you were not getting an error for using the wrong name.

Comment: Thanks a lot dude.